# Does the Windows Experience Index (WEI) affect actual performance?

Tags: windows, windows-experience-index

The Windows Experience Index shows the user different values based on the hardware installed within their computer.  After installation of new hardware, these values need to be recalculated.

Besides being informational to the user about areas in which they may look into improving performance, does Windows use these values to enable/disable or limit performance of Windows itself?  If so, what does it limit?  What if a system has new hardware installed, but never update the values?

Comment: Windows does not use the numbers for anything.  It is perfectly happy if its never done.

Comment: @Ramhound that may not exactly be the case.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

As there is no clear documentation on how **Windows Experience Index** affects performance at first it appears to be just for ones [bragging rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/achieving-a-perfect-windows-experience-index-score-in-windows-7#section_2)

But found two links which hints that Windows Experience Index does affect  performance directly by disabling/enabling features or indirectly by providing data.

### Does Windows use these values to enable/disable or limit performance of Windows itself? What does it limit ?

Yes it does enable/disable Aero feature.

Line 2 of para 2 in this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Assessment_Tool) quotes

> For example, the Aero graphical user interface will not automatically be enabled unless the system has a WEI score of 3 or higher

### What if a system has new hardware but never updated the values ?

Another resource [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markmoro/2012/02/19/windows-7-solid-state-drives-and-why-a-winsat-score-matters/) & [here](https://windowsengineering.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/windows-7-and-the-ssd-defrag-mystery/) describes in fine detail how important it is to run WinSAT when you have new SSD. Which could be true for other hardware as well but if I spend any more time on this, I would feel like a rep wh**e

I am quoting the important bits below

> When an SSD is  detected the following things are not used, readyboot,
>   readyboost, Superfetch and disk defragmentation. The Superfetch
>   service looks at the following registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Winsat\DiskScore every 30 minutes. If the regkey is
>   65 or greater, which means the disk has the performance of an SSD, it
>   sets the Superfetch service to manual.

Both the examples above does not address performance degrading subjects but it just goes on proving the fact that Windows Experience Index plays some part in performance optimization

### Update

This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn938327(v=vs.85).aspx) mentions how running WinSAT optimises Windows for running on SSD

> When you install Windows to a SSD, we recommend that you run
>   WinSAT.exe formal to help optimize Windows for use on SSD. This
>   reduces the number of write operations that Windows makes to the SSD,
>   and makes other optimizations.

Reports and reviews from its release time claim *WinSAT will adjust the level of the operating system's features to match the capabilities of hardware* but it is little strange when there is so very little to describe how and what.

I must end this now :D

Comment: `if I spend any more time on this, I would feel like a rep wh**e` if you are able to find more information about this, please provide it.  Don't ever feel like it's a bad thing to provide as much detail as you can.